# Pagefile on Windows 10 limited to 64 GB?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, swap, pagefile

I have a few tasks where I can't avoid using tons of memory. Since I have limited physical memory, Windows starts using the SWAP/Pagefile. Though it seems that Windows is limiting the pagefile size to 64 GB, no matter what. I tried to change the pagefile size manually but the task manager always shows me something with 64 GB max. Since I need a bit more than that I always experience crashes and blue screens.

Is there any way to remove this limitation? I have enough space on my SSD left to support quite huge pagefiles.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1208251/what-is-the-largest-size-for-windows-pagefile-sys-you-can-set

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1. the programs you execute are somehow flawed or ineffective and take too much RAM 2. your physical RAM is too small for the set of programs you execute. Have you tried to the RAM problems on application level, may be reducing the memory a program uses via a config file (virtual machine based programs like Java have a lot of configuration memory related options that can have a large impact).

Comment: Those are quite big calculations I run. They just need this amount of RAM unfortunately. And yes... my physical RAM is too small but unfortunately it is soldered onto the board and I cannot upgrade it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagefile will only ever be 3x the amount of RAM you have, or 4GB, whichever is higher.

> 3 × RAM or 4 GB, whichever is larger. This is then limited to the volume size ÷ 8. However, it can grow to within 1 GB of free space on the volume if required for crash dump settings.

Source https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/determine-appropriate-page-file-size

Comment: ah thanks! Is there a way to circumvent this? Something to trick Windows into allowing more?

Comment: @Tommy - The limit cannot be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was correct as far as it goes, but note that the Source link given says that this is for "System-managed page files".

You can choose that your page file Not be system-managed, by turning off "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives", and then selecting "Custom size" instead of "System managed size".  When you do that, you can set an Initial size and Maximum size to whatever you want, but of course you do need free disk space.

This is on the Virtual Memory Dialog page, which can be reached from System Properties, Advanced Tab, Performance heading - Settings... button, Advanced Tab (of Performance Options), Virtual memory - Change... button.  To get to System Properties from Windows 11, go to Settings, System, About, Related Links, Advanced system settings.  Or just search for "Advanced system settings" in the settings search field.

Comment: I believe OP's question implies they've already set a manual Pagefile size, and that they cannot set it higher than 64GB, of if they do, the system only creates a 64GB Pagefile regardless. Is what you are saying contradicting that? OP isn't asking WHERE to make those changes, and that is all your answer appears to be saying. If you have more relevant information to add, please edit your answer. If this is just a comment, welcome, but please note that this area is reserved for answers, and comments will be deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234743)